# ASP.Net MVC - Implementing a Test Environment

Tags: c#, design, unit-testing, testing, asp.net

I would like to implement some sort of test environment for ASP.Net projects. I am trying to implement this as an alternative to mocking the entity framework.

Here is what I am trying to achieve :

1. Two `DBContext` classes are used, one for development, one for tests.
2. These two `DBContext` classes will generate 2 databases through `Enable-Migration`/`Update-Migration`. Again, one for development, one for tests.
3. Adding a new migration must be applied to both the development environment and the test environment.

Basically, the development database and test database must be identical. Therefore, my goal is to find a way so that we only have to run each type of command once to control both environments :

- `Enable-Migrations` creates two migration configuration classes.
- `Add-Migration` can be applied to the two environments.
- `Update-database` applies the migrations on both environments.

Here is my attempt first attempt at the context classes :

```
namespace Project.DAL
{

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
        public Context() : base() { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pool> Pools { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Match> Matches { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invitation> Invitations { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dev : Context
    {
        public Dev() : base("project_dev") { }
    }

    public class Test : Context
    {
        public Test() : base("project_test") { }
    }
}
```

How would you guys approach this? I am coming from the Ruby On Rails framework, which has a development/test environment similar to what I am looking for.

This is with the code-first approach. So ideally, if one were to create a new project, he designs his models and applies migrations to populate/create two databases representing your development and test environments.

Comment: Are the two databases identical?  Just change the connection string.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've forgot to mention something important : this is with the code-first approach. So ideally, if one were to create a new project, he designs his models and applies migrations to populate/create two databases representing your development and test environments.

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea.  Have two identical databases, one EF context, two connection strings.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In that case, what do you mean exactly by changing the connection string? There might be something that I didn't explain properly...

Comment: I would use database snapshots

Comment: In my tests, I hand my constructor methods a DBContext that uses the connection string for a Test database.  If you keep the connection string in APP.CONFIG, you might not even need to think about it, as the Test project already has its own APP.CONFIG.

Comment: Also, recommended reading: [**What does Code First really mean?**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx) ... *based on the name, most folks think of Code First as defining a model in code and having a database generated from that model. In actual fact, Code First can be used to target an existing database or generate a new one. There is tooling to reverse engineer a Code First model based on an existing database...rather than a third alternative to Database & Model First, Code First is really an alternative to the EDMX file format.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey This seems interesting. Now for the other part of my question, how would you apply new migrations to both databases?

Comment: Um... The same way you apply new migrations to one database?

Comment: Why not just put the connection string in the configuration as @RobertHarvey mentions.  This is more of a .net way of doing things